# tkinter collapsible in 3-column layout makes columns jump

Tags: python, tkinter, multiple-columns

For tkinter in python, I created a collapsible widget that shows/hides some content on click. I found an example on [this site](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/collapsible-pane-in-tkinter-python) and adjusted it to my needs.

What I try to do is to put multiple collapsibles into a 3-column layout. The problem is that opening a collapsible in one column causes the other columns to "jump". This effect can be seen when running the example code below. It seems that if the content of the collapsible is longer than the length of both labels in the header of the collapsible (i. e. the text "Collapsed" and the "+" character) the colums begin to jump because the other one is getting expanded. I already experimented with settings like columnspan, sticky, etc. on all different levels of parent and child widgets, but nothing worked.

Does anyone have an idea on how to make the 3-column layout without the "jumping" effect? If there exists a totally different approach to reach the goal, I would be glad to get some hints!

Here is the example code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

# Collapsible class
class Collapsible(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):

        # Call __init__ of parent class
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # Setting weight to the first column makes the second column "float".
        # This puts the "+" and "-" characters to the right of the column.
        self.columnconfigure(index=0, weight=1)

        # If value=0, collapsible is initially closed.
        # If value=1, collapsible is initially opened.
        self._variable = tk.IntVar(value=0)

        # Frame for clickable header of collapsible
        self.header_frame = tk.Frame(self, name='header_frame', bg='yellow')
        self.header_frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.header_frame.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e: self.toggle())
        self.header_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ew')

        # Frame for content of collapsible
        self.content_frame = tk.Frame(self, name='content_frame', bg='green')

        # Call _activate method
        self._activate()

    def _activate(self):

        # Remove all child widgets from header frame
        for child in self.header_frame.winfo_children():
            child.destroy()
        
        # Closed: self._variable.get() = 0
        if not self._variable.get():
            # Labels in header frame if collapsed
            collapsed_header_1 = tk.Label(self.header_frame, text='Collapsed', bg='purple')
            collapsed_header_1.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e: self.toggle())
            collapsed_header_1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nw')
            collapsed_header_2 = tk.Label(self.header_frame, text='+', width=2, bg='purple')
            collapsed_header_2.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e: self.toggle())
            collapsed_header_2.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='ne')

            # Forget the content frame if collapsible is closed
            self.content_frame.grid_forget()

        # Opened: self._variable.get() = 1
        elif self._variable.get():
            # Labels in header frame if expanded
            expanded_header_1 = tk.Label(self.header_frame, text='Expanded', bg='purple')
            expanded_header_1.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e: self.toggle())
            expanded_header_1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nw', )
            expanded_header_2 = tk.Label(self.header_frame, text='-', width=2, bg='purple')
            expanded_header_2.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e: self.toggle())
            expanded_header_2.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='ne')
            
            # Show/expand the content frame if collapsible is opened
            self.content_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='new', columnspan=2)
    
    def toggle(self):
        # Change value of self._variable and call self._activate
        self._variable.set(not self._variable.get())
        self._activate()


# Test the collapsible
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create app and give it a name
    app = tk.Tk()
    app.title("Collapsible Test")

    # Open app in full screen size
    screen_width = app.winfo_screenwidth() 
    screen_height = app.winfo_screenheight()
    app.geometry("%dx%d" % (screen_width, screen_height))

    # Configure the 3-column layout
    app.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    app.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    app.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

    # Define the 3 columns (= 3 frames with grid layout)
    column_frame = None
    column_frame_1 = tk.Frame(app)
    column_frame_1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='new')
    column_frame_2 = tk.Frame(app)
    column_frame_2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='new')
    column_frame_3 = tk.Frame(app)
    column_frame_3.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='new')

    j = 0
    for i in range(11):

        # Check to which column the content should be added
        if i >= 0 and i <= 2:
            column_frame = column_frame_1
            j = 0 if i == 0 else j
        elif i >= 3 and i <= 5:
            column_frame = column_frame_2
            j = 0 if i == 3 else j
        elif i >= 6:
            column_frame = column_frame_3
            j = 0 if i == 6 else j

        # Create collapsible
        collapsiblePane = Collapsible(parent=column_frame)
        collapsiblePane.pack(fill='both', expand=1)

        # This is the content of the collapsible
        mytext = 'My '+str(i)+'. Label that contains a text.' if i < 9 else 'My '+str(i)+'. Label that contains an even longer text. The other columns are "jumping"!'
        label = tk.Label(collapsiblePane.content_frame, text=mytext, justify='left', anchor='nw')
        label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nw')

        # Raise the counters
        i=i+1
        j=j+1

    # Start the app
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please reduce the code to [mre]!

Comment: Should all three columns appear on the screen at the same time, or can they be tabs in [ttk.Notebook](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/complex.html#notebook)?

Comment: Yes, the App is designed to display all 3 columns at the same time, and not in tabs with ttk.Notebook.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is to do something with the text. You can use the `wraplength` option of the Label widget ([integer or dimensional units](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/dimensions.html)). Or you can use [`textwrap.fill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.fill) to avoid word breaks: `text=textwrap.fill(mytext, width=10)`.